# BigQuery: how to pass default value as x in case of null in value in a string field

Tags: google-bigquery

i was trying to hardcode a column with value as x when ever there is a null value occurence is appearing i have tried the below query to check but still i see blanks in the column

e.g.

```
**column - product_subcategory**

select 
ifnull(tbl.product_subcategory,'x') as product_subcategory
from dataset.layer_dim.tbl;
```

i was not able to hardcode as x even after testing the above query anything i am missing ?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, but you might be seeing empty string instead of null values. Try use `NULLIF` to transform blank values into `NULL`:

```sql
with sample as (
  select '' as product_subcategory
  union all
  select null as product_subcategory
  union all
  select 'x' as product_subcategory
  union all
  select 'some value' as product_subcategory
)
select 
ifnull(nullif(product_subcategory, ''), 'x') as product_subcategory
from sample;
```

Output:

```
x
x
x
some value
```

Comment: many thanks it works , can you please also check this as well seems complex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041648/how-to-check-the-conditions-on-string-and-float-columns-in-bigquery